# How to root and install new android OS on flipkart digiflip xt712 tablet

Tags: android

I bought a new tablet from flip-kart and now I want to root it and install a new android OS into it... 
I surfed a lot but no success please can anyone tell me how can I do it..?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What tablet do you have (Brand / Model). You can checkout http://www.cyanogenmod.org/

Comment: Its Digiflip Pro XT712  its manufacturer is flipkart itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please pay attention: Rooting your device will void the warranty! Also your device can get bricked or damaged during the Rooting process. Perform this process at your own risk.**

It seams to be pretty easy to root the Digiflip Pro XT712 (If you are using Windows).

There are tutorials on

- http://androidsigma.com/root-digiflip-pro-xt712/
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-digiflip-pro-xt712-t2801545.

**They booth do the same:**

> Your tablet should have more than 80% of battery present in it.
>   You need a Windows PC for this tutorial as this method will only work on Windows PC.
>   The method will void the warranty of your device.
>   USB Debugging should be enabled on your tablet. To enable USB Debugging go to Settings > Developer Options > Enable USB Debugging.

**If you do not see Developer Options you have to enable them:** 
Open Settings> About> Software Information> More.
Then tap “Build number” seven times to enable Developer options. ...
Go back to Settings menu and now you'll be able to see “Developer options” there.
Tap it and turn on USB Debugging from the menu on the next screen.

**Download the following tools:**

- MTK Droid Tools http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49597819&postcount=922
- ADB usb driver http://ge.tt/2yL21VT/v/2.

**How to root:** (from http://androidsigma.com/root-digiflip-pro-xt712/)

- Extract the rooting files which you downloaded before. Once you have extracted the MTK Droid tools, open it and connect your tablet to your computer.
- You will see a Root button at the bottom of the software. Click on the button. Above you will find a tab named root, backup and recovery. Click on that tab and then select Boot from phone Press Recovery and boot option.
- You will be asked if you want automatic CWM recovery of not. Press **Yes**
- You will be asked if you want to flash patched boot.img Select **No**.
- Press on **Yes** button when you are asked to install created recovery to phone.
- If you want to reboot your tablet in recovery mode press **yes** on the next dialog box you see.

Comment: Normally you don't thank on Stackoverflow but accept the answer or upvote :) I'm glad I could help you